# Complementary of a regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get all the string that does not match these two regular expressions:

```
\d{2}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{4}

\d{2}[:]\d{2}
```

I have tried using:

```
/^((?!REGULAR_EXPRESSION_HERE).)*$/
```

But does not work.

Anyone know how it should be done? I can't use the re.split() function of python because I am using the regular expressions tool of Scrapy.

Comment: Sorry, what does brackets between `-` and `:` do?

Comment: @utdemir Oh, you can forget about them, it's the same if you remove them. I think that they are use when you want to work with a range [1-9].

Comment: Python's regular expressions are not enclosed in slashes. Are you sure you're talking about Python?

Comment: @lanzz The two regulars expressions that I have put above are working properly in python. The other stuff, /^((?!REGULAR_EXPRESSION_HERE).)*$/, it's just something that I have found to calculate the opposite and it isn't working.

Comment: Can you use a replace or re.sub method?

Comment: What do you try to match with this "complementary" regular expression? Any string which does not match any of the first two patterns?

Comment: @HansZauber Yeah, that is what I want to get.

Comment: So why not trying to match against both, and accept if none matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?P<date>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})|(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2})
```

#### Sample code

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import re

text=("01-01-2014 13:15\n"
"foo bar\n"
"\n"
"Some text: blah bla !\n"
"Some ranges:\n"
"1-\n"
"-1\n"
"12-\n"
"-12\n"
"1-2\n"
"12-3\n"
"Strange date: 08-99-1999\n")

pattern = re.compile(r"(?P<date>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})|(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2})")

result = pattern.sub("", text)

print( result )
```

#### Output

```
\n 
foo bar\n
\n
Some text: blah bla !\n
Some ranges:\n
1-\n
-1\n
12-\n
-12\n
1-2\n
12-3\n
Strange date: \n
```

**NOTA:** I have added the `\n` otherwise they are not visible in the answer.

Tested on **Python 2.7.4** and **Python 3.2.3**

Comment: Thank you very much, I can't give you the vote up because I don't have the enough reputation yet... :(

Comment: @AritzBi I think you can now , dont'you ;)